# C# Backgroundworker: What way to periodically update a PictureBox?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker, picturebox

I'm using a BackgroundWorker to periodically check a hardware switch. Due to it is connected via a slow RS485 network, I have to delay the next status update.
On switch Status change I want to update an OK/nOK Picture Box. This is realized as a green OK pictureBox over a nOK pictureBox. No real work is done here.

For expandability I decided to use the Backgroundworker. Finally I want to have a hidden worker, which

1. provides globally the Status of three switches and
2. updates on StatusChange the PictureBoxes.

**Problem description**
Once the BackgroundWorker is started, it works as expected. However the GUI freezes.

**What did I try?**
The [MSDN BackgroundWorker Class Note 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)
says, that GUI should be updated via ProgressChanged. I tried to raise this Event by Worker_Switch.ReportProgress(fakeProgress++) and failed. The PictureBox wasn't updated anymore.

*Snippet from designer*

```
this.Worker_Switch = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
// 
// Worker_Switch
// 
this.Worker_Switch.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
this.Worker_Switch.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.Worker_Switch_DoWork);
```

*Snippet from Main Form*

```
delegate void SetEventCallback(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e);   // Threadsafe calls for DoWork

private void btnBackgroundworker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Worker_Switch.IsBusy)
    {
        Worker_Switch.RunWorkerAsync();                              
    }
}

private void Worker_Switch_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Worker Thread has no permission to change PictureBox "pictureBoxSwitchrightOK"
        // Therefore this method calls itsself in the MainThread, if necessary.
    while (!Worker_Switch.CancellationPending)
    {
      if (this.pictureBoxSwitchrightOK.InvokeRequired)              // Worker Thread
    {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
        SetEventCallback myCall = new SetEventCallback(Worker_Switch_DoWork);
        this.Invoke(myCall, new object[] { sender, e });
    }
    else                                                            // Main Thread
    {
        // Turns OK Picture Box invisible, if nOk State (Switch pushed)
        pictureBoxSwitchrightOK.Visible = SwitchOK("right");  // true: OK (green)
        this.Refresh();

    }
}

private bool SwitchOK(string rightOrLeft)               // select one of the switches
{ (...)}                                    // gets hardware switch status
```

**Edit:** Special Thanks to laszlokiss88 (3 possibilities) and JMK (for simplicity with `System.Windows.Forms` Timer from toolbox)

This alternative from Toolbox also worked:

```
this.timer_Switch.Enabled = true;
    this.timer_Switch.Interval = 400;
    this.timer_Switch.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer_Switch_Tick);

    private void timer_Switch_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    motorSwitchControl.Init();        // globally available Switch status                                               
    SwitchRight = SwitchOK("right");
    SwitchRightOK.Visible = SwitchRight; 

    SwitchLeft = SwitchOK("left");    // globally available Switch status
    SwitchLeftOK.Visible = SwitchLeft;  
    SwitchAllOK = SwitchRight & SwitchLeft;
    this.Refresh();
}
```

a) Is it correct, that the Sleep() actually happens in the Worker Thread?
- no Main Thread

b) What is going wrong, if I manipulate user interface objects in DoWork? (Contrary to MSDN Note)
- works in Main Thread?

c) What is the correct way to periodically update a PictureBox? DoWork, ProgressChanged, RunWorkerCompleted...?
- Three possibilities from laszlokiss88 answer.

Comment: if you want to manipulate controls within threads then you need `Dispatcher` class to do so.

Comment: Not necessarily. The ProgressChanged event handler executes on the thread that created the BackgroundWorker (most likely it is the UI thread).

Comment: I would suggest to go for Delegate. Just do a google search for "delegate to update the ui"

Comment: Windows Forms has it's own, thread-safe, timer. Can't you use it to check the status of your switch, and then update the picture box if needs be?

Comment: @JMK. Sounds like a good idea to use from `System.Timers` the `ElapsedEventHandler`. I'll try to improve this way.

Comment: There are a number of timers, the one in `System.Timers` runs on a seperate thread, the one inside `System.Windows.Forms` runs in the same thread as the UI, making it much easier to update UI elements. If your application is a Windows Form, I would use a Windows Forms Timer from the toolbox, and do your check and update of the picturebox inside the `Timer_Tick` event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the UI from the DoWork event via the Dispatcher, or Control.Begininvoke(winforms), or you can do it via the ProgressChanged event of the BackgroundWorker:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // You are in the main thread
        // Update the UI here
        string data = (string)e.UserState;
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // You are in a worker thread
        (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(0, "right");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a start you should almost never have a need to put an active background thead to sleep. I am also not sure why you are constructing/defining the delegate this way, try some thing like

```
public delegate void UpdatePictureBox();
myDelegate = new UpdatePictureBox(UpdatePictureboxMethod);
```

then you have a method `UpdatePictureBoxMethod`

```
private void UpdatePictureBoxMethod()
{
    this.pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.SomeImage;
}
```

or something simalar, where you pass in the image to update to.

Alternatively you could use the `(bgWorker as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(progress, object);` method. So from the background thread you call

```
(bgWorker as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(progressBarValue, infoBall);
```

where here class `IfoBall` will hold all your important information

```
class InfoBall
{
    public int nProgressBar { get; set; } 
    public int nMaxProgressBar { get; set; }
    public Image image { get; set; }
}
```

then you can pass this object back to the UI thread and do your updates

```
void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // On UI thread.
    InfoBall someBall = (InfoBall)e.UserState;
    this.pictureBox1.Image = someBall.image;
    // etc...
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting the hardware switch information over a slow RS485 network. I'm new to C#, but I think it is a good idea to have a Delay to the next switch status request?